# Extend an options to all the pages in website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

is there a way to extend a single header ( navigational options), footer and few other options throughout a website. as we do in Django(using the extend option).

Answer (score 0):

Not using pure HTML - you'll need some kind of templating language. It can be done using PHP, since it's commonly available on pretty much all webservers.

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: i am using .net jquery. anything along those lines?

Comment: Then yes, I believe .NET has this functionality. I believe a search for "include files in .NET" will yield plenty of results.